# Help Deriving the Canonical Form of this Elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation

So I'm given the following PDE, for which I'm to derive the canonical form:

$$u_{xx} + u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0.$$

Clearly $A=1, B=1/2$ and $C=1$.

Hence we have $\xi_x/\xi_y = -1/2 +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, which gives

$$-2\xi_x = (1-\sqrt{3} i) \xi_y.$$

It's here that i'm having trouble solving for ξ , it's probably very simple but could anyone guide me through it? I'm thinking I should seperate the variables and integrate but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm fine after that (as η is the same process). Thanks!

I know that the solution I *should* get is $\xi = (x-2y) -  \sqrt{3} i \, x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say that $B = 1/2$? If you identify the coefficients from the $PDE$:

$$Au_{xx} + B u_{xy} + C u_{yy} =0, \quad u = u(x,y), \quad (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2,$$

then you have $A = B = C = 1$ and the discriminant is:

$$\Delta = B^2-4AC = -3 < 0, $$

so the PDE is elliptic, as you already know. The characterstics are to be found from the equation:

$$A \xi_x^2 + B \xi_x \xi_y + C \xi_y^2 = 0,$$

so it yields (since $A,B,C$ are not zero):

$$\left( \frac{\xi_x}{\xi_y} \right)^2 + B \left( \frac{\xi_x}{\xi_y} \right) + C = 0,$$

and we have the characteristics given by:

$$\frac{\xi_x}{\xi_y} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i = - \frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Integrating the equation above, you obtain the two (complex) characteristics as follows:

$$\xi = \phi_+ x + y, \quad \eta = \phi_- x + y,$$

where $\phi_{\pm}$ are the two different roots of the previous equation.

I hope this is useful to you.

Cheers!

---

Notice that the result that is expected to be obtained holds. Indeed, if you expand $\phi_+$ and $\phi_-$, you will obtain:

$$-x+2y+\sqrt{3} i\, x = 2 \xi = \overline{\xi}, \quad -x+2y - \sqrt{3}i \, x = 2 \eta = \overline{\eta},$$

where the overlined characteristics remain equally constant (even if you multiply them by $-1$).

---

**Edit**: notice that you can obtain two real characteristics by performing the following *trick*:

$$\begin{array}{l} \overline{\xi}+\overline{\eta} = 2x+4y \equiv u, \\ i(\overline{\xi} - \overline{\eta}) = -2 \sqrt{3}x \equiv v.\end{array} $$

Comment: I took B to be a half as, whereas you take the coefficient of the xy derivative to be B, I've always been shown to take this as 2B and hence taken the discriminant to be B^2 - AC. Thank you for your explanation, I think I understand now!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Char. equation:
$$a\,dy-(b-\sqrt{b^2-ac})\,dx=0.$$
Then
$$\mathit{dy}-\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3} i}{2}\right) \, \mathit{dx}=0$$
$$y+\frac{\sqrt{3}  i x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}=C,$$
$$\xi=Re\left(y+\frac{\sqrt{3}  i x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=y-\frac{x}{2},\\\eta=Im\left(y+\frac{\sqrt{3}  i x}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3} x}{2}.$$
Canonical form is
$$u_{\xi\xi}+u_{\eta\eta}=0.$$